# LINQ (Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am facing a problem while using LINQ concept.
below i am comparing two datatables one is filled by database another is by excel file.

Problem is when I am apply join between two "tempdt" contains double value which promoting an error of casting object.
I can't change return type from string to double cause it could be any data type in future as currently it is double it might be alpha numeric in future.

```
    var commonRows = from r1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
                             join r2 in tempdt.AsEnumerable()
                             on r1.Field<string>(0) equals r2.Field<string>(4)
                             select r2;
            if (commonRows.Any())
            {
                abcdefgh = commonRows.Count();
                dt123 = commonRows.CopyToDataTable();
                // ring the ghanta of gutlu
            }
```

> *Exception: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type
>   'System.String'.*

Comment: Is the Dataset Type safe or not? You also may check type of excel file file column type.

Comment: what is the type of double value field in tempdt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136302/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-parsesystem-string-meth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code is working for me.

thanks every one

```
    var commonRows = from r1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
                             join r2 in tempdt.AsEnumerable()
                             //on r1.Field<object>(0).ToString() equals r2.Field<object>(4).ToString()
                             on r1[0].ToString() equals r2[4].ToString()
                             select r2;
            if (commonRows.Any())
            {
                abcdefgh = commonRows.Count();
                dt123 = commonRows.CopyToDataTable();
                // ring the ghanta of gutlu
            }
```

Comment: except that is a horrible way to compare doubles, which seems to be what you are doing here...

Comment: @jeroenh : no one comparing doubles here. i put this method to compare two data tables.

Comment: @jeroenh : or if u r talking about the way i convert it to string then may be [string.Format("{0}", r1[0])] this way is fine for you?

Answer (score 6):

Here is where I think your problem is:

```
from r1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
join r2 in tempdt.AsEnumerable() on
r1.Field<string>(0)  //<-- this may not be string
equals 
r2.Field<string>(4) //<-- this may not be string
select r2;
```

What you *could*  do is to treat it as object:

```
from r1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
join r2 in tempdt.AsEnumerable() on
(string.Empty + r1.Field<object>(0)) <-- Edited by Andreas X
equals 
(string.Empty + r2.Field<object>(4)) <-- Edited by Andreas X
select r2;
```

What you *should* do, is to make sure your index numbers (0 and 4) points to the same type.

Edit: I usually use the old ASP-trick to aboid null pointers when asking to the tostring value.

Comment: while using your concept i am getting below error

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: i cant make them of same type cuase r2.Field<object>(4).ToString()  is coming from user side in a form of excel which i am converting into datatable.

Comment: Ok - I just assumed the two datatables where from your own database :)

Answer (score 2):

Casting to string isn't really possible, since double and string are 2 completely unrelated classes. perhaps try comparing their .ToString() values. Or if you want to be completely safe, compare their string formats, so you don't get any NullReferenceExceptions: `string.Format("{0}", fieldvalue)`

Answer (score 0):

Field expects the underlying datatype to be a string.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301394.aspx

InvalidCastException
The value type of the underlying column could not be cast to the type specified by the generic parameter, T.

You could use object to ignore the type as Jens Kloster purposed.
However, there is something wrong with your design if you don't know the datagtype of your columns.

Comment: how can i come to know which type of value user giving in his excel file. he could give fractional value or may b integer only or alpha numeric.

Comment: 1. user will not do it all the time.
2. from my end i tried it but still it is giving the same error cuase uts value remains same only it visualisation change when we do formating in spread sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by a mismatch datatypes between properties' entity and underlying table columns.