# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method,

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, int, int32

I am using Entity Framework, and I have a line of code that convert string field (id)to int and compare with a number

```
 students = students.Where(s => (Int32.Parse( s.id)>5555));
```

Whenever I try to run it I receive rhis error. "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

I have tried seveal different things and nothing is working, so any help would be great.

Comment: Did you try `Convert.ToInt32` ?

Comment: yes.it didnt work.and caused that error

Comment: Try this `Int32.TryParse`

Comment: If your `model.id` have db type `int`, why you even need to to parse it to int in linq2entities? I think you should repair your model and not cast at all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework/Linq EXpression converting from string to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694716/entity-framework-linq-expression-converting-from-string-to-int)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210526/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-parsesystem-string-meth)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly I would highly recommend against converting the column into an int, you lose the indexing on the column. You rather convert the int into a string. However here is how to fix your code.

1. Firstly sign the [Contributor License Agreement](https://cla.msopentech.com/).
2. Then you [fork the Entity Framework git repo](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/create/fork).
3. Write a new `MethodCallTranslator.CallTranslator` which will take `Convert.ToInt32(string)` and replace it with `(int) string`.
4. Register the new `MethodCallTranslator.CallTranslator` within `MethodCallTranslator`.
5. Write unit tests for your test case.
6. Check in
7. Create Pull Request
8. Wait
9. Download new version of Entity Framework from nuget

Comment: Great step by step tutorial, +1